# How to use Canvg javascript library offline in a browser without server?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon, serverless, canvg

I'm developing a Firefox extension and for security issues I need to use **Canvg** offline, in a browser without server. I would like to use it in a pure js script. I have read the documentation but there isn't information about it.
Could you kindly help me? Thank you all.

I tried to export the project from github (https://github.com/canvg/canvg.git) and to import it in my project, but not work...

Comment: I have exactly the same question. Things are getting difficult nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working:

- download latest release (`Source code (zip)`) from here: https://github.com/canvg/canvg/releases
- unpack the zip and navigate to the folder
- do a `yarn install`
- run `npm start`

  - this will create `/dist/umd.js`
- take a look at `/test/browser/index.html`[1] on how to use it locally / offline

[1] https://github.com/canvg/canvg/blob/master/test/browser/index.html